# How to retrive the varchar value of SQL SERVER database to an array using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am having a database name "fees" where I have declared different columns say tutionfee, computer fee, admissiofee etc.

Now I only want to retrieve the value of tutionfee to an array. So I can use it any where. I am using C#

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("select * from fees where admno = @admno", con);
```

Comment: use SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method and change you query to return only tutionfee like this " select tutionfee from fees where admno=@admno"

Comment: collect the query info in a datatable and loop through that datatable and assign those into array

Answer (score 1):

If you know exact row count of your select command, you can create a string array and use [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get this column value in a loop.

Let's say your select statement returns 10 row, you can use it like;

```
var array = new string[10];

using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using(var check = new SqlCommand("select * from fees where admno = @admno", con))
{
    // Add your parameter value.

    using(var reader = check.ExecuteReader())
    {
       int i = 0;
       while(reader.Read())
       {
          array[i] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("tutionfee")); 
          i++;
       }
    }
}
```

If you don't know your array size in compile time, you can use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `Select Count(*)...` command to get your row count first or you can use `List<string>` instead.

Comment: This solution is good but not great because you are assuming the column index.

Comment: Because you are not freeing your resources properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found with assoc arrays:

```
List<string> tutionfees = new List<string>();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from fees where admno = @admno", conn))
{
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admno", "value"); //set your value
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            tutionfees.Add(rdr["tutionfee"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:** More resource inexpensive solution.
**Edit 2:** Added consideration for setting the value of prameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SqlDataReader` and loop though all rows to construct what you need.

I prefer `Linq` and code below returns a `List` (if needed modify to `Array`) with all the your table data.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(cnString))
{   
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from fees where admno = @admno", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@admno", SqlDbType.Varchar, "");
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {           
            return reader.Select(r => new 
                          {
                              TutionFee= r["tutionfee"] is DBNull ? null : r["tutionfee"].ToString(),
                              ComputerFee= r["computerfee"] is DBNull ? null : r["computerfee"].ToString(),
                              AdmissionFee= r["admissiofee"] is DBNull ? null : r["admissiofee"].ToString()
                          }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

All properties are of `string` type, but if you know the `Type` of the column you can use them.

Comment: Opening connection is unnecessary because `SqlDataReader` does that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(6), tutionfee) + ',' AS 'data()' 
FROM fees
FOR XML PATH('')
```

OR

```
declare @ID varchar(max)='' 
select @ID=@ID + Convert(varchar(6),ID) +',' from  INDEXES
select @ID
```

Use this query else is fine. So now you can use the execute scalar command and return value will be comma separated list and easily converted to array using `result.split(',');`

Answer (score -1):

```
        SqlConnection con = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("select * from fees where admno = @admno", con);          

           SqlDataReader rdr = null;

            rdr = check.ExecuteReader();

         ArrayList  array= new ArrayList();

            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                array.Add(rdr["tutionfee"].ToString())

            }
```

Comment: i know generic collection are better but didn't know he had idea about generic that is why i gave him simpest code..